# Sybase isql limits output to six decimal places - How to get around this?

Tags: sql, sybase, isql

I'm trying to get floating point data from a Sybase database, exactly as it's stored, using isql in a shell script to be able to copy it to another table. The problem I've run into is that it rounds these numbers to at most six decimal places. This behaviour is noted in the documentation (exact quote, "isql displays only six digits of float or real data after the decimal point, rounding off the remainder."), but I'd still like to find a way around it since I don't have any other tools to work with.

I've tried using CONVERT and CAST in my queries, to both DOUBLE and VARCHAR, but with no luck.

Is there any way to get around this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly convert it on the server side to maximum precision, e.g. 
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,18), your_col) FROM your_table

Comment: Forgot to add conversion to a string:SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(60),CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,18)), your_col) FROM your_table